# Replacing Magnolias JCR to hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jcr, magnolia

Is it possible to abandon the use of Magnolias JCR and introduce hibernate instead. JCR is very restrictive when in comes to complex data queries so it would be desired to user hibernate instead which would provide defined data models on which we could directly execute standard (My)SQL queries.
If so, how? and what would be the right approach ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, see the [Non-JCR Content App](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Content+app+with+non-JCR+content) documentation.

In short, you will need to create custom [ContentConnector](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Content+connector) that will provide your data (from Hibernate or any other source) to Magnolia in an unified form. Then you can use the data in both Content Apps (Magnolia Admin UI) and templates.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! nonetheless, how magnolia will handle security when hibernate is introduced, currently it seems that security is managed per node basis? but with hibernate in the picture the nodes will no longer be used

Comment: Exactly. You will have to take care of the security in your connector implementation (use [MgnlContext.getUser()](https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/repositories/magnolia.public.sites/ref/5.4.3/apidocs/info/magnolia/context/MgnlContext.html#getUser()) to get the current user).

Comment: great thanks, i think we are getting somewhere! once i get the user how would i approach n setting permissions for each attribute in the module, would i have to consider spring security ?